# Привести к HashMap

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap

Есть класс

```
class UserData : RealmObject() {
var name: String = ""
var value: String = ""
}
```

В конструкторе другого класса необходимо использовать данные переменнык таким образом, чтоб обращаясь к данному классу я получал HashMap

Comment: HashMap состоящий из чего?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ну HashMap это же и есть пара двух параметров(ключ значение).
и хочу так раз таки чтобы на месте ключа был name из класса UserData а на месте значения был value.

Comment: Нет. HashMap - это **набор** пар ключ-значение. Вот я и спрашиваю, где у вас `набор`?

Comment: Создайте HashMap и добавьте в него элемент. Не забудьте, что ключ должен быть неизменяемым, а у вас name объявлен как var.